# How to apply a modifier one by one on all selected objects in blender in Python

Tags: python, add-on

I am new to python and blender and working on multiple objects. Is there a way to apply same modifier to each and every selected object at once?

Answer (score 2):

there is a pretty handy add-on called "modifier-tools" which come with Blender, just enable it:

[image]

then you can select multiple objects you can apply modifiers here:

[image]